# How can I prevent next variable of struct being printed?

Tags: c, string, struct, memcpy

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct fruit {

    char one[6];
    char two;

};
typedef struct fruit Fruit;

int main() {

    Fruit *a = (Fruit*) malloc (sizeof(Fruit));
    char* a1 = "apple";
    memcpy(a->one, a1, 6);
    a->two = 'Z';


    Fruit *b = (Fruit*) malloc (sizeof(Fruit));
    char* b1 = "banana";
    memcpy(b->one, b1, 6);
    b->two = 'Z';

    printf("a->one is %s, b->one is %s\n", a->one, b->one);

}
```

output is

```
a->one is apple, b->one is bananaZ
```

As you see, when I try to print a->one (apple), it's fine. But when I try to print b->one which has its full size, it reaches next variable and prints bananaZ. How can I prevent these things to happen? I want to make it print banana without changing fruit structure.

Comment: `"banana"` isn't 6 bytes long, it is 7 bytes. When you copy only 6 you lose the end-of-string marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
memcpy(b->one, b1, 6);
```

to :

```
memcpy(b->one, b1, 7);
```

accordingly to your previous `memcpy`, where string `apple` is copied. In that case, you have 5 letters in your string but the length you pass to `memcpy` is `6` in order to include the termination character `\0`. In the same logic, `banana` has 6 letters, therefore in order to include the termination character `\0`, the length passed to `memcpy` has to be `7`.

> want to make it print banana without changing fruit structure.

But this is not a correct policy. If you want to keep words of length 6+, you must change your structure. You cannot be writing words larger than `one`'s size.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to modify

```
struct fruit {

    char one[6]; //<== put a 7 instead of 6
    char two;

};
```

The end of a string is `"\0"`.
If you set a string of size 6 and your word is "banana" (6 also) then you don't have the place for the `"\0"` and you start reading things you don't want in memory.

Answer (score 0):

In `C`, strings are null terminated, the last byte of your string has to be the ascii value 0 => '\0'.

So if you want to copy a string of 6 bytes in a buffer, you have to allow 7 bytes with the last one set to 0.